# Netbeans "Watch" equivalent for Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, xdebug, watch

Is there an equivalent to Netbeans "Watch Expression" in Eclipse PDT for PHP debugging.  The Netbeans Watch keep causing a socket exception, so the feature is pretty much useless.  Does Eclipse have something similar, where you can enter in an expression using the current variables and watch them update as you debug the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Netbeans watch gives a socket exception, it means there is a bug in Xdebug. You'd get the same errors in Eclipse PDT. In Xdebug 2.1.3 a few of those cases where fixed (and even more in GIT), so if you're not on 2.1.3 yet, you can try that.

Comment: +1 for the response, and I would add another +1 for assuming the responsibility

Comment: I am on 2.1.3, no success.  it debugs fine, but after like 5 minutes of debugging (stepping through each line individually) it crashes.